# DropDownListFor in a gird selected value is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code

```
ViewBag.Years= new SelectList(new[] 
 { new { ID = "1", Name = "1 Year" }, 
   new { ID = "2", Name = "2 Year" }, 
   new { ID = "3", Name = "3 Year" }, 
 }, "ID", "Name", "");
```

Here I am trying to bind in my table for every row

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Records.Count; i++ ) 
{ 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Years, 
       (SelectList)ViewBag.Years}) 
}
```

Model[i].Years sends different value for every row but still it is not selecting the correct item.

[image]

Comment: Where does `i` come from? Why are you not using `item`?

Comment: I forgot that I used the for loop than foreach, I change the code please look one more time.

Comment: Can you share your model class? You do `Model.Records.Count` but then also access `Model[i]`. Do you have a custom indexer? You also don't use the parameter to your lambda expression. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";



        var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(a => new myViewModel
        {
            Description ="Description"+a,
            Years =GetYear(a)  
        }).ToList();



        return View(data);
    }

    private List<SelectListItem> GetYear(int a)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(y => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = y==a?true:false,
            Text = y + " Year",
            Value =y.ToString()
        }).ToList();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

 //Model class is bellow
public class myViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }
}


Demo :
```

[image]